# OSGi: Conditional Permission Admin OR User Admin

Tags: java, security, permissions, osgi

Are Conditional Permission Admin and User Admin services in OSGi complementary or exclusive? I am developing a home automation project based on OSGi and I am not sure if I should implement both security services or not.

The application will eventually be accessible through the internet but there would not be a group of user with accounts. From my understanding 'User Admin' service is more ideal for a website or an application that will have dedicated users that need to be authenticated. In my case, the application might communicate with another application residing in different location so it might also need some form of authentication. But wouldn't the security gain by implementing 'Conditional Permission Admin' user be enough?

My plan is to use the 'Conditional Permission Admin' and create custom conditions to control special actions such us sharing resources with other bundles. Is it enough or shall I implement both. Also will having both services running affect the performance of the system significantly?

I would really appreciate if someone share their view on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConditionalPermissionAdmin is about setting code based permissions checked by the SecurityManager. UserAdmin is about holding user credentials and assigning roles to users which can be examined by code using the UserAdmin API. UserAdmin has nothing to do with the SecurityManager. So CPA and UA are pretty orthogonal.

Having a SecurityManager installed is a performance hit. UserAdmin has no similar performance issue since it is only checked when called explicitly.

Comment: 1. Will the performance hit from CPA affect an application like home automation too much? I would expect a little bit of performance drop should be acceptable to get better security.                                                         2. And say if I have only 2 or 3 external users wouldn't the security options like custom conditions in CPA be enough? Or do I still need UserAdmin on gateway?

Comment: As for performance, you will need to measure it. But installing a SecurityManager means many places will start checking permissions which is not without cost. A SecurityManager is best for keeping code away from other code. Like if you had bundles from multiple parties running on the gateway and wanted to make sure they were kept apart. If you already trust all the code then a SecurityManager is probably overkill. Something lighterweight like UA would be better and less costly.